# What is our stance on questions asking for a percentage related to traveling? On-topic or off-topic as being a statistical question?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

What is our stance on questions asking for a percentage related to traveling? On-topic or off-topic as being a statistical question?

Examples of questions asking for a percentage related to traveling:

- [The percentage of “missed flights”](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21717/1810)
- [What fraction of those using Express Lanes at UK immigration have to see an officer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/131110/1810)
- [Rate of acceptance of UK transit visas for Indians](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155010/1810)

I'm asking as I have seen a [comment](http://archive.is/rlHuY) on the question [What percentage of international flights departing from Manila are cancelled due to Duterte's lockdown on Metro Manila from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154940/1810) stating:

> The percentage question doesn't seem to be a travel question, just a stats question?

Which means questions asking for a percentage related to traveling should be closed. So I'm confused. Please clarify the scope policy.

Comment: To clarify, that comment did NOT say "question asking for a percentage related to travel should be closed".  IT was a question asking you what the problem you faced was, which you've left out.

Comment: @MarkMayo I see.  the actual question that is how easy it is to fly out from manila to another country despite the lockdown. But if I use the term how easy, people will close vote as opinion-based.

Comment: Franck, if there is just one plane going, but you are on that plane, you can travel. If almost all planes are going but you can not get on those planes, you are stuck. That is one reason I do not think this a useful question.

Comment: @Willeke "If almost all planes are going but you can not get on those planes" -> how would that happen? Regarding the rest of your comment: Life is a stochastic process and knowing percentages/probabilities is helpful to make decisions. My decision I know that almost all planes are going (I'd do nothing special) to be different than if only 1 plane is going (I'd be actively trying to book it, or making plans for long-term stay in Manila).

Comment: @ChrisH 1) I posted 223 questions in main, and only 13 questions in Meta. I think it enhances the user experience to have decently clear rules. I don't take close votes from them personally, I think that both Mark and Willeke are good mods, we just disagree from time to time, which is expected as we have hundreds of posts 2) "posting 20 practically indistinguishable questions" -> what? first time I hear that.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt forget it, that comment was unnecessary and I shouldn't have posted it.